# Turtle graphics in Python 2.7: Drawing an arc

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics, approximation

In Exercise 4.1(c) in Section 4.12 (Chapter 4) of *[Python for Software Design](http://greenteapress.com/thinkpython/pythonsd.html)* it is claimed that the following version of function `arc()`,

```
def arc(t, r, angle):
    """Draws an arc with the given radius and angle.
    t: Turtle
    r: radius
    angle: angle subtended by the arc, in degrees
    """

    arc_length = 2 * math.pi * r * abs(angle) / 360
    n = int(arc_length / 4) + 1
    step_length = arc_length / n
    step_angle = float(angle) / n

    # making a slight left turn before starting reduces
    # the error caused by the linear approximation of the arc
    lt(t, step_angle/2)
    polyline(t, n, step_length, step_angle)
    rt(t, step_angle/2)
```

is "better" than the original one from Section 4.7:

```
def arc(t, r, angle):
    arc_length = 2 * math.pi * r * angle / 360
    n = int(arc_length / 3) + 1
    step_length = arc_length / n
    step_angle = float(angle) / n
    polyline(t, n, step_length, step_angle)
```

(You can look up the code of subroutines, such as `polyline()`, [here](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/code/polygon.py)).

I'm trying to understand why the former version is better, in particular, by which metric. How can we define the true circle we are approximating? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for a reason beyond the one in the comment? Also, the former is supposedly better, not the latter.

Comment: Exactly, I don't see how the two versions are different in terms of approximation error (after considering a few simple examples).Thanks for catching a semantic error, now fixed.

Comment: Not that it answers your question about *why* one is better than the other, but I'd like to point out that this is [already implemented anyway](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/turtle.html#turtle.circle).

Comment: Is the source code for [this implementation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/turtle.html#turtle.circle) published somewhere? -- it might give some clues as to the merits of approximations proposed in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a bake-off to compare.  We'll use `turtle.circle()` as an arbitrary standard and then use the two `arc()` routines to draw 360 degree arcs (aka circles), one 3 pixels smaller radius, one 3 pixels larger radius than our standard:

```
import math
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def polyline(t, n, length, angle):
    """Draws n line segments.

    t: Turtle object
    n: number of line segments
    length: length of each segment
    angle: degrees between segments
    """
    for _ in range(n):
        t.fd(length)
        t.lt(angle)

def arc2(t, r, angle):
    """Draws an arc with the given radius and angle.
    t: Turtle
    r: radius
    angle: angle subtended by the arc, in degrees
    """

    arc_length = 2 * math.pi * r * abs(angle) / 360
    n = int(arc_length / 4) + 1
    step_length = arc_length / n
    step_angle = float(angle) / n

    # making a slight left turn before starting reduces
    # the error caused by the linear approximation of the arc
    t.lt(step_angle/2)
    polyline(t, n, step_length, step_angle)
    t.rt(step_angle/2)

def arc1(t, r, angle):
    arc_length = 2 * math.pi * r * angle / 360
    n = int(arc_length / 3) + 1
    step_length = arc_length / n
    step_angle = float(angle) / n
    polyline(t, n, step_length, step_angle)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(500, 500)
screen. setworldcoordinates(-250, -50, 250, 450)

thing0 = Turtle()
thing0.circle(200, steps=60)

thing1 = Turtle()
thing1.color("red")
thing1.penup()
thing1.goto(0, 3)
thing1.pendown()
arc1(thing1, 197, 360)

thing2 = Turtle()
thing2.color("green")
thing2.penup()
thing2.goto(0, -3)
thing2.pendown()
arc2(thing2, 203, 360)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Complete Circles

[image]

Detail #1

[image]

Detail #2

[image]

I would say that the Section 4.12 arc (green) looks better than the Section 4.7 arc (red) as the green arc has less jaggies and stays a consistent 3 pixels away from our standard circle whereas the red arc veers closer and further.  What criteria do you consider important?

Answer (score 0):

I could not explain it to myself also until I tried to sketch it. If you can imagine it, the turn of half a step angle helps to bisect the arc length approximately. By going in between, it is kind of a rough correction to both add and subtract the additional areas created.